# I added a MySQL database and now retrieval tests from a SEPERATE H2 database fail. Commenting out MySQL config makes tests pass

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have a chess application written with Spring boot. I has two databases. One `H2` database for quick and short term data retrieval (to support game pairing) and a `MySql` database for long-term data persistence (chess game storage). I am using `Hibernate` and `JPA` for my `ORM`. As soon as I configured the Mysql database and figured out how to make the correct `EntityManagerFactory` be injected to `H2AbstractRepo` (supposed to be the one defined in `H2Config.java`), I noticed I could save, but retrieval tests from the `H2` database failed.

To debug the issue, I created a line in my `save` method where after the entity gets saved, I immediately attempt to retrieve it again (See `save()` in `H2AbstractRepo`). This is ALWAYS successful.

But when `save` returns back to my `H2PlayerRepoTest.findById()` test method and the test attempts to retrieve the object from from the database to assert it was properly saved, the result comes back `null` suggesting there is no `entity` associated with that Id despite what I explained in the paragraph above. I am simply perplexed.  IMPORTANT: If I comment out the contents of `MySqlConfig.java` effectively remove the MySql database from the application the problem disappears, suggesting the `MySql` database may be the culprit. Here are the relevant config files and the `repo` classes.

`H2Config.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
public class H2Config{

    @Bean("h2DataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .addScript("classpath:sql_scripts/create_dbs.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("h2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean("h2HibernateProperties")
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
        properties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean("H2PersistenceUnit")
    public EntityManagerFactory h2EntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.chess.model.entity");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdaptor());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    @Bean("h2JpaVendorAdapter")
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdaptor() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }
}
```

`MySqlConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
public class MySqlConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().toString());
            logger.warning("PropertyVetoException throw assigning the database driver");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chesslive");
        dataSource.setUser("springstudent");
        dataSource.setPassword("springstudent");
        dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(3000);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
        properties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);

        return properties;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.chess.model.entity");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
    }
}
```

`H2AbstractRepo.java`

```
@Transactional
public abstract class H2AbstractRepoImpl<T extends AbstractEntity> implements AbstractRepo<T> {

//    TODO remove this and logging statements
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().toString());
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public H2AbstractRepoImpl(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(T entity) {
        logger.info("Persisting entity: " + entity.toString());
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        logger.info("Attempting to retrieve the entity for verification");
        var result = this.findById(entity.getId());
        if (result == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Entity failed to be retrieved after saving");
        } else {
            logger.info("Entity successfully retrieved: " + entity.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T entity) {
        if (entityManager.contains(entity)) {
            entityManager.remove(entity);
        } else {
            var newEntity = entityManager.merge(entity);
            entityManager.remove(newEntity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T merge(T entity) {
        return entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Object id) {
        var entity = entityManager.find(clazz, id);
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> findById(Object id) {
        logger.info("Attempting to find entity with Id: " + id.toString());
        var entity = entityManager.find(clazz, id);
        return Optional.ofNullable(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return (List<T>) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM " + clazz.getSimpleName() + " e").getResultList();
    }
// If i dont specify the unitName EntityManagerFactory defined in MySqlConfig takes is injected.
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "H2PersistenceUnit")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

The test in question

```
@Test
void findById() {
    Player player = new Player();
    UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    player.setId(id);
    player.setUsername("dylan");
    playerRepo.save(player);

    Optional<Player> dylanOpt = playerRepo.findById(id);
    if (dylanOpt.isEmpty()) {
        fail();
    } else Assertions.assertTrue(true);

}
```

Last but not least, my (Partial) logs. Please take note of the print statements from the `H2AbstractRepo.save` method near the bottom. They illustrate the object can be retrieved immediately after saving.

```
2020-12-11 15:49:56.317  INFO 14504 --- [           main] c.e.c.db.repo.impl.h2.H2PlayerRepoTest   : Starting H2PlayerRepoTest using Java 11.0.1 on DESKTOP-G477CDL with PID 14504 (started by super in C:\Users\super\Documents\SpringProjects\ChessLite)
2020-12-11 15:49:56.322  INFO 14504 --- [           main] c.e.c.db.repo.impl.h2.H2PlayerRepoTest   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-11 15:49:57.602  INFO 14504 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-12-11 15:49:57.651  INFO 14504 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 33 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-11 15:49:58.184  INFO 14504 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@6920b0bc' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-11 15:49:58.219  INFO 14504 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-12-11 15:49:58.972  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:f236f47e-b2c4-4baa-9f91-02be17045b54;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2020-12-11 15:49:59.544  INFO 14504 --- [g-Init-Reporter] com.mchange.v2.log.MLog                  : MLog clients using slf4j logging.
2020-12-11 15:49:59.689  INFO 14504 --- [           main] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry         : Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.5 [built 11-December-2019 22:18:33 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
2020-12-11 15:49:59.995  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-12-11 15:50:00.092  INFO 14504 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.23.Final
2020-12-11 15:50:00.327  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2020-12-11 15:50:00.604  INFO 14504 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-12-11 15:50:01.804  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-12-11 15:50:01.819  INFO 14504 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-12-11 15:50:01.866  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-12-11 15:50:01.909  INFO 14504 --- [           main] c.m.v.c.i.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource   : Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 1hge1a3aen6qdyf17t752r|3b7c80c6, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hge1a3aen6qdyf17t752r|3b7c80c6, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 5, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chesslive, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 3000, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {password=******, user=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
2020-12-11 15:50:02.498  INFO 14504 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-12-11 15:50:02.664  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-12-11 15:50:02.664  INFO 14504 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-12-11 15:50:02.811  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
2020-12-11 15:50:02.835  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
2020-12-11 15:50:03.517  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/img.chesspieces.wikipedia/**'] with []
2020-12-11 15:50:03.517  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/libraries/**'] with []
2020-12-11 15:50:03.517  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/css/**'] with []
2020-12-11 15:50:03.525  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/js/**'] with []
2020-12-11 15:50:03.525  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'] with []
2020-12-11 15:50:03.802  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@182fd26b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6c1a63f7, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@534d0cfa, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6d946eee, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1317ac2c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@53917c92, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@8ee1404, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@5dc120ab, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@b5311cb, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@8636cf4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@49c4118b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1d33e72e, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@59ec5a0b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@f287a4e]
2020-12-11 15:50:03.920  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'messageBrokerTaskScheduler'
2020-12-11 15:50:04.058  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'brokerChannelExecutor'
2020-12-11 15:50:04.710  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
2020-12-11 15:50:04.710  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry@15c96f24]]
2020-12-11 15:50:04.718  INFO 14504 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
2020-12-11 15:50:04.719  INFO 14504 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-12-11 15:50:04.720  INFO 14504 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-12-11 15:50:04.746  INFO 14504 --- [           main] c.e.c.db.repo.impl.h2.H2PlayerRepoTest   : Started H2PlayerRepoTest in 8.958 seconds (JVM running for 10.755)
2020-12-11 15:50:05.036  INFO 14504 --- [           main] c.e.chess.db.repo.impl.h2.H2PlayerRepo   : Persisting entity: Player{id=679f9535-2d1e-4be6-9335-8d75ffda15c3, username='dylan', gameList=null, joinDate=null} com.example.chess.model.entity.Player@6eeeb9da
2020-12-11 15:50:05.069  INFO 14504 --- [           main] c.e.chess.db.repo.impl.h2.H2PlayerRepo   : Attempting to retrieve the entity for verification
2020-12-11 15:50:05.069  INFO 14504 --- [           main] c.e.chess.db.repo.impl.h2.H2PlayerRepo   : Attempting to find entity with Id: 679f9535-2d1e-4be6-9335-8d75ffda15c3
2020-12-11 15:50:05.078  INFO 14504 --- [           main] c.e.chess.db.repo.impl.h2.H2PlayerRepo   : Entity successfully retrieved: Player{id=679f9535-2d1e-4be6-9335-8d75ffda15c3, username='dylan', gameList=null, joinDate=null} com.example.chess.model.entity.Player@6eeeb9da
2020-12-11 15:50:05.090  INFO 14504 --- [           main] c.e.chess.db.repo.impl.h2.H2PlayerRepo   : Attempting to find entity with Id: 679f9535-2d1e-4be6-9335-8d75ffda15c3
```

Comment: Lot of config here. Maybe start with adding `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to your test classes, and annotate services that you want to keep off tests with `@Profile("!test")`

Comment: Its not really a testing issue per se. The tests just reveal the bug. Both databases are going into the production product so if they are interfering with one another it needs to be fixed.

Comment: OK, then I got the issue wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After toying with the `MySqlConfig` I have figured out the answer. The hint is that commenting out the `MySqlConfig.java` makes all tests pass. The culprit bean is the `EntityManagerFactory` bean. There are two beans of this type in my project but the one in `MySqlConfig` is labeled with `@Primary` making it the default bean when there are more than one `EntityManagerFactory` beans,

```
@Primary
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.chess.model.entity");
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
}
```

and another defined in`H2Config.java`.

```
@Bean("H2PersistenceUnit")
public EntityManagerFactory h2EntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.example.chess.model.entity");
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdaptor());
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
}
```

Removing `@Primary` exposes the conflict that was being masked. Where does the conflict manifest? In the `PlatformTransactionManager` bean defined in `H2Config.java`.

```
@Bean("h2TransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}
```

This bean has a dependency on a `EntityManagerFactory`. The issue for me was that this bean does not need to be explicitly  injected so I was completely unaware that anything *was* injected. Only after removing `@Primary` from `MySqlConfig.transactionManager()` and seeing the `NoUniqueBeanDefinition` exception did I realize what was happening.

Since I did not explicitly inject a `EntityManagerFactory` into the `PlatformTransactionManager` it retrieved the dependency itself by defaulting to the "primary" bean defined in `MySqlConfig.java`. This caused unexpected behavior and while I don't understand completely why saves worked but retrievals didn't (something with which data source is being used when a save is initiated vs. a read) its predictable that getting these dependencies tangled would result in persistence issues. In any case the solution is quite simple: remove the ambiguity by manually injecting `EntityManagerFactory` defined in `H2Config` into the `PlatformTransactionManager` bean in the same class.

```
@Bean("h2TransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(h2EntityManagerFactory());
}
```

Now all tests pass. Thanks for coming to my TED Talk!